# Could I get to an element using two ids?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code:

```
<div id='layer1'>
    <div id='a'>
    <div id='b'>
<div id='layer2'>
    <div id='a'>
    <div id='b'>
<div id='layer3'>
    <div id='a'>
    <div id='b'>
```

I want to try to get the element [a] of layer1. 
Could I do this using pure javascript and withOUT jquery and other stuff?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There should be no more than one element with a particular ID in a document

Comment: Classes would be better, at which point you can do `document.querySelector(".layer1>.a")` to get the one you want.

Comment: Use classes or data attributes instead of id's

Answer (score 2):

An ID uniquely identifies one single element on the page. The behavior you described is more like "a class" inside of an ID:

```
document.querySelector("#counter-for-drinks .up-arrow")
```

and so if you want a different `up-arrow`, it is:

```
document.querySelector("#counter-for-burgers .up-arrow")
```

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is what is similar to jQuery `$(" ")`. It also has the form [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for getting all matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is missing closing tags. You can always validate your code [here](https://validator.w3.org/). 
Also, you should use `class` instead of `id`.

```
<div id='layer1'>
  <div class='a'></div>
  <div class='b'></div>      
</div>
<div id='layer2'>
  <div class='a'></div>
  <div class='b'></div>
</div>
<div id='layer3'>
  <div class='a'></div>
  <div class='b'></div>
</div>
```

You can use javascript to get elements:
`document.querySelector("#layer1 .a")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var firstA = document.querySelectorAll('#layer1 #a');
var nodeString = '';
if (firstA.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < firstA.length; i++) {
    nodeString = nodeString + firstA[i].innerText + '<br/>';
  }
}
document.getElementById('founded-nodes').innerHTML = nodeString;
```

```css
#founded-nodes {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id='layer1'>
  <div id='a'>layer1 aaa</div>
  <div id='b'>layer1 bbb</div>
</div>
<div id='layer2'>
  <div id='a'>layer2 aaa</div>
  <div id='b'>layer2 bbb</div>
</div>
<div id='layer3'>
  <div id='a'>layer3 aaa</div>
  <div id='b'>layer3 bbb</div>
</div>

<div id="founded-nodes"></div>
```

As all said in above over comments and answers, one must use a single id on the same page, or else the use of classes is a must. But if you want to achieve this, you can have a look at code.